# How do you add a footer with CSS display: table?

Tags: css, footer, css-tables

A lot of positioning problems seem to be easily solvable with the CSS display: table rule, so I thought I'd give it a try. The only problem is when I do, the footer completely disappears and I don't understand why.

html:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" id="main_section">

<!--Main section-->
  <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-11" id="main_col">
    {% block navbar %}
      {% navbar %}
    {% endblock %}
    <hr/>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
    <div class="footer">  
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

css with sass:

```
#main_section {
  padding: 0;
  #main_col {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    .footer {
      position: relative;
      height: 20px;
      background: gray;
      color: gray;
      display: table-row;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to copy an example from this codepen:

http://codepen.io/colintoh/pen/tGmDp

but the footer just isn't showing up. How would you go about fixing this?

edit:

CSS:

```
#main_section {
  padding: 0; }
  #main_section #main_col {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    display: table; }
    #main_section #main_col .footer {
      position: relative;
      height: 20px;
      background: green;
      color: green;
      display: table-row;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      width: 100%; }
```

And I'm using Firefox right now.

Comment: One reason to avoid display table is it has some odd behaviors in IE still.

Comment: I haven't a clue what you are showing in your HTML. In your CSS, is that SASS or something?

Comment: Edit: editted the main question to add css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
width:100%;
```

To your footer. Otherwise it will only take up the space needed to fit the content inside. Also, some browsers do not allow for empty divs. Add some content to your footer, and it should show up in your browser. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rq9nm772/1/

Comment: The footer's still not showing up for some reason. Is there something else that usually interferes in this case?

Comment: Sometimes a browser won't allow an empty div. As soon as I added some content to the footer in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rq9nm772/1/ it showed up. Also, you need to add width: 100% to the parent dive in order for the footer to take up the entire width of the screen. If you don't want that parent div to be 100%, you'll have to move the footer outside the parent div and make the #main-col div width:100%;